# Deactivate Google's voice recognition on Android 4.4

Tags: android, root, google-search

**Device**: Asus Padfone 2 on Android 4.4.2 Kitkat (rooted).

**Headphones**: audio technica ath-m50 (wired).

**Music app**: Poweramp Pro, Headset commands/buttons deactivated.

**Problem**: When I am hearing to music (doesn't matter wich app) and I put my phone in my pocket, a dark gray google voice window pops up, stops my music and starts voice recognition. It is really annoying, so I  sent it to Asus to fix the problem. After repair, the problem remained. In Android 4.1 it was possible to deactivate the Google-Search app (this solved the problem). I read, that in 4.4.2 the launcher is linked to the Google-Search app, and deleting it would possibly brick my device.

I even forbid the Google-Search app to access the microphone via "App Ops", but it didn't work. Google Now is deactivated (not installed) as well as the hotword. Problem occures with active password lock and without. If my phone is awake, the Google-Search app starts right away, not the dark gray window like in the lockscreen.

Flashing a custom ROM is no option, becuase I am bound to asus ROM to be able to use the tablet dock.

Picture: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9ljJ1znjbZ7bmVaYndJQm9Ra2s/edit?pli=1

Comment: Recommending closure as off topic, since this is about generally using Android, not programming it.

Answer (score 0):

Its called "Hotword Detection".

Have you tried [this](http://androidadvices.com/turn-off-ok-google-hotword-detection-android-kitkat/)?

Comment: Yes I have turned it off, problem remains.